# Apache POI generates different content than Excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am writing a application that reads multiple .csv files and reduces the number of rows.

Output from the application is a excel file (.xls).  This file(s) us uploaded to shops as BOM's.

It works nicely for all shops except one. On that shop I gets a result "can't read file".

Of a coincidence I noticed that If I opened same file in Excel,, and then saved it again, the shop accept it.

Somehow directly generated files differs from files opened and saved in Excel.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void writePurchaseList(String path, List<PurchaseItem> list)   {

    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

    Sheet studentsSheet = workbook.createSheet("BOM");
    final String[] header = new String[] { "quantity", "description","orderNo" };

    int rowIndex = 0;
    int cellIndex = 0;
    Row row = studentsSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
    row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(header[0]);
    row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(header[1]);
    row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(header[2]);

    for(PurchaseItem item : list){
        cellIndex = 0;
        row = studentsSheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
        row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(item.getItemQuantity());            
        row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(item.getDescription());
        row.createCell(cellIndex++).setCellValue(item.getOrderNumber());
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path+".xls");
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Anyone that have a idea what I am doing wrong?

//lg

Comment: If you open the file in Excel, and do a Save-As, what format does it default to? And if you try reading the file with Apache POI 3.15 beta 1 (or newer!), do you get a more helpful file type exception?

Comment: It defaults to *.xls  I am using 3.14. Is there any reason to think 3.15 will solve this ???

Comment: 3.15 has more helpful error messages if you give it files of an unsupported type

Comment: I am trying 3.15 beta1. Same result when writing files. Then I added a small snippet to open same file that just was written. No errors is shown. I am not so familiar with Apache POI,, is there a way to turn on logging?

Answer (score 0):

I recall having a similar problem many years ago with Apache POI workbooks. I think it may have been related to the missing cell policy for the workbook when null values were written to cells. You could try to set the workbook missing cell policy with:

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
workbook.setMissingCellPolicy(Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
```

Comment: Tried this. Does not help me. Any other defaults or policies to set ?